# SQL: insert data into free column acording to date difference

Tags: sql, if-statement, sql-insert, etl, business-intelligence

I have got a problem. I'm a real beginner at SQL. I work on BI project and I need to create data warehouse.

My current problem is this:

I have a table into which I push data from an external Microsoft Access. That data contains two dates (billing info) and I need to generate an info into this table if there is delay in payment (there is free column in the table named `delay` into which I need to generate `YES`/`NO` according to if the date of payment is later then date of "need" of payment)

So I have in mind something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE billing,
VALUES (YES)
IF DATE1 > DATE2,
ELSE VALUE (NO)
```

... I know this is no SQL but its just to get the idea.

If someone know something which could help me I would be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: There's `CASE` operator in ANSI SQL: http://docs.faircom.com/doc/sqlref/#33399.htm: `...VALUES (CASE WHEN DATE1 > DATE2 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Insert into table(col1,col2,col3) Select   
Case When Date 1> Date2 Then 'No' Else 'Yes' End as Col1,  
Case When Date 1> Date2 Then 'No' Else 'Yes' End as Col1,col3  from table 2


update tablename set Col8 = Case When Col3> Col4 Then 'No' Else 'Yes' End
```

Above update statement will work for all the rows in the table if the col3> col4 will update as 'No' and if not it will update as 'yes'. hope this is clear

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how and why it solves the problem and doesn’t introduce others.

Comment: Question is can I use this if col1 and col2 already have data in it and I want to insert data only into Col3 (billing) .. .if so then End as Col1 means the column into which I will insert the data (YES/no)?

Comment: Not clear with your question. If already data in col1 and col2 then you need to use update statement

Comment: Yes.. Col1 and Col2 has the value to insert for col1 and col2.  you can even leave with out col1

Comment: Well maybe I wasnt clear enough ... In column 1 column2 etc. there are already data which I do not want to change .. and there is column 8 (named billing) into which I want insert the mentioned data (YES/NO) acording to date difference ... And I want to do it for every entry in the table (about 5k rows) ... I hope its more clear now .. To be honest I dont know if I should use insert or update ...